# Get the COUNT of data for last 4 years monthly by using CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MONTH(ENCOUNTER_DATE) 'MONTH',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ENCOUNTER_DATE >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()) THEN CUSTOMER_ID END)  ,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ENCOUNTER_DATE >= DATEADD(YEAR, -2, GETDATE()) THEN CUSTOMER_ID END),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ENCOUNTER_DATE >= DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE()) THEN CUSTOMER_ID END),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ENCOUNTER_DATE >= DATEADD(YEAR, -4, GETDATE()) THEN CUSTOMER_ID END)
FROM 
    PATIENT_ENCOUNTERS
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(ENCOUNTER_DATE)
ORDER BY 
    MONTH(ENCOUNTER_DATE)
```

The count of every month data is getting added to the next year of the same month.

I cross checked with the below query where the data is not matching

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(ENCOUNTER_DATE), COUNT(CUSTOMER_ID) 
FROM 
    PATIENT_ENCOUNTERS
WHERE 
    ENCOUNTER_DATE >= DATEADD(YEAR, -4, GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(ENCOUNTER_DATE)
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(ENCOUNTER_DATE) DESC
```

Can someone help me to find the data monthly in last 4 years by using case statement only.

Comment: its confusing, can you show some basic data and then output you required via excel.

Comment: FYI its not a case *statement* rather a case *expression*. And you need to show sample data and expected results in order for us to assist.

Comment: Why `DISTINCT` when you have a `GROUP BY`? And you should quote column names by using brackets `[MONTH]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're setting a begin date but not an end date. Try something similar to the following.

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN ENCOUNTER_DATE >= DATEADD(YEAR, -4, GETDATE()) AND ENCOUNTER_DATE < DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE()) THEN CUSTOMER_ID END)
```

Comment: @SmitaAnde Great, I'm glad that it's working! If this answer helped you, please take a moment to mark it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(ENCOUNTER_DATE) 'MONTH',
COUNT(CASE WHEN year(ENCOUNTER_DATE) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN CUSTOMER_ID END)  ,
COUNT(CASE WHEN year(ENCOUNTER_DATE)= YEAR(GETDATE())-1 THEN CUSTOMER_ID END),
COUNT(CASE WHEN year(ENCOUNTER_DATE)= YEAR(GETDATE())-2 THEN CUSTOMER_ID END),
COUNT(CASE WHEN year(ENCOUNTER_DATE)= YEAR(GETDATE())-3 THEN CUSTOMER_ID END)
FROM PATIENT_ENCOUNTERS
GROUP BY MONTH(ENCOUNTER_DATE)
ORDER BY MONTH(ENCOUNTER_DATE)
```

Here with `YEAR(GETDATE())` I got the year of current year and with `YEAR(GETDATE())-1` year part of last year and so on. Then I have compared this year with year of encounter_date as `year(encounter_date) = YEAR(GETDATE())` to get the `customer_id` of that year which are grouped by later by month.

To get the year wise cumulative count:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(ENCOUNTER_DATE) 'MONTH',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN year(ENCOUNTER_DATE) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN CUSTOMER_ID END)  ,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN year(ENCOUNTER_DATE)>= YEAR(GETDATE())-1 THEN CUSTOMER_ID END),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN year(ENCOUNTER_DATE)>= YEAR(GETDATE())-2 THEN CUSTOMER_ID END),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN year(ENCOUNTER_DATE)>= YEAR(GETDATE())-3 THEN CUSTOMER_ID END)
    FROM PATIENT_ENCOUNTERS
    GROUP BY MONTH(ENCOUNTER_DATE)
    ORDER BY MONTH(ENCOUNTER_DATE)
```

Comment: Hii,
This query has also worked to present the data in detail monthly for each year.
Thanks